# What happens if my shield breaks?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I've noticed my shield only seems capable of taking a few hits, at least right now, so I'm leery about using it.

If my shield breaks, is it completely useless, or are there some attacks it is still able to block?  Furthermore, is it possible to repair a broken shield?

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: i found the sheilds very usfull in the first couple doungeons if used right. if you swing the nun chuck at the right moment the shield takes NO Damage. if you are using it wrong then you will lose your sheild.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you completely destroy your shield, you lose it forever and will have to buy a new one.  If your shield is close to breaking, make sure you repair it back at the **Bazaar** or use a **Revitalizing Potion**.  Otherwise don't use it if you wish to save it.

You can always upgrade your shields so they would be more durable and can take more damage (2 additional levels of upgrades) but they can still be destroyed.

One of the shields can auto-repair over time, the **Sacred Shield** (the third available at the **Bazaar**).  It can still be damaged and destroyed like the others, you'll just have to take a break from using it to allow it to repair itself.

There is an indestructible shield too that you can get later in the game, the [**Hylian Shield**](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Hylian_Shield). You can get that winning the **Boss Rush** mode.

Comment: As I played through the game, I hardly ever used the shield.  IIRC, you don't really need it for the first dungeon at all.  The `Octorocks` pose little threat and could just be ignored.

Comment: Thus far I haven't been using it as well, since it just doesn't seem worth it. It can only take a handful of hits, so it seems rather useless.

Comment: Well, you will need the shield eventually to make some boss battles much easier.  It took me a while for me to figure that I needed it.

Comment: @JeffMercado I was under the impression that you needed the shield to beat Stalfos, who appears as a mini-boss in Dungeon 1.

Comment: @Powerlord: No you don't really need it. You may need to dodge at times but I wouldn't say the shield is really necessary there.

Comment: how do you apply the revitalizing potion to the shield

Comment: @brian: If your shield is damaged, just equip the **Revitializing Potion** and use it (press `A` again).  Link will automatically put it on the shield and you get **4 Hearts** of health refilled.

Comment: You all do know that correct usage of the shield (i.e. by thrusting the nunchuck), do you? If you do it correctly, with the correct timing, then the shield will block without taking any damage (plus it does the shield attack).

Comment: @poke: Though I would think it is still subject to any effects however.  Like you can't still shield bash a fire enemy with a wooden shield or an electric enemy with the iron shield.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yeah, sure, you have to keep in mind what shield you are using, but it’s definitely not useless (more or less in response to Wipqozn’s comment).